Boost Converter Efficiency Input Current
I'm trying to learn about DC-DC Boost converters and with the help of WEBENCH I've made this circuit:

Parameters are:

Vin: (4.95 - 5.05) V
Vout: 17 V
Iout: 300mA
Efficiency: 95.2%

My main questions are:

Efficiency is defined as Pout/Pin. So, in order to get 300mA at the output, will I need at least 1.10A of input current from the main power source?

$$ Eff = \frac{P_{out}}{P_{in}} = 0.952 = \frac{17 (V)\cdot 0.3(A)}{5 (V)\cdot I_{in}(A)}\rightarrow  I_{in} \approx 1.07 A $$

If \$ I_{in} = 500 mA \$ , does it mean that, with 95.2 efficiency, the boost will output \$ I_{out} = 140 mA \$?

The purpose of this circuit is to boost an USB line from 5V (and the 500mA of max current allowed in USB 2.0) to 17V and aprox. 300mA of max output current, is there any other better alternative?


Thx in advance.

Points 1 and 2 are correct.
Point 3:
No circuit can create energy out of nothing, and there are always losses, so Pout < Pin. Thus if you want 17V 300mA (5.1W) you will need more than 5.1W on the 5V input. Accounting for efficiency and safety margins, tolerance on the input voltage which may only be 4.5V thus need more curret for the same power... you'd need 5V 1.5A for example.
So your options are:

Check if you really need 5.1W on the 17V side, maybe you don't.

Specify a 5V 2A "cellphone charger" power supply which will deliver the required current (but it won't work with a standard PC USB port)

Use USB-C power delivery to negotiate the current/voltage you need, this then requires an USB-C port to plug in

Use 3 USB ports in parallel like in the good old days of external USB harddrives that used a little bit more current than they really should (with the obvious tradeoff of being ridiculous)

Reduce the power consumption to less than say 2W on the 17V side. If you only need 300mA for short bursts you can use capacitors to lower the average power, but that tends to get problematic (ie, large) quickly and won't work if the 300mA are drawn for more than a few tens of milliseconds.




Efficiency is defined as Pout/Pin. So, in order to get 300mA at the output, will I need at least 1.10A of input current from the main power source?

Yes (or at least 1.07+ A).

If \$I_{in}=500\$ mA, does it mean that, with 95.2 efficiency, the boost will output \$I_{out}=140\$ mA?

Yes

The purpose of this circuit is to boost an USB line from 5V (and the 500mA of max current allowed in USB 2.0) to 17V and aprox. 300mA of max output current, is there any other better alternative?

\$5 \text{V} \times 500 \text{mA} = 2.5 \text{W}\$
\$17 \text{V} \times 300 \text{mA} = 5.1 \text{W}\$
You can't get more power out than you put in. So this will not work.

Here's how I see it...

Maximum input power is 5 volts x 500 mA = 2.5 watts
You want 17 volts x 300 mA which is 5.1 watts

You're not going to get this if you want the 17 volts to be continuously supplying 300 mA.
